# WordPress custom CSS class for page title

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to WordPress and now I have some issue with my own custom theme.

Because I use Twitter Bootstrap as framework for my theme, there exist a CSS class `text-right` and this one I want to use for my page title in WordPress.

But I have no idea if or how it is possible to add a own custom CSS class to the page (or post) title.

Can anybody please help on this issue?

Comment: If it's not frequent, just use inline styling.

Comment: My opinion is, Before you directly go with WordPress, Make custom template with pure `CSS and HTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out in which page you need custom title (page is a singular page or a post page). then edit the related file and add your custom class to title.
refer the following link for finding out your required page.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thanks Ann, that's one solution for my issue... but in other cases the answer from @AliGajani is also another possible solution.